# 2 almost identical activities in 2 projects, but 1 doesn't have toolbar

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-activity

When I normally create a new project, the activities have toolbars on top like this:

[image: like this]

But somehow, I'm a noob so I managed to somehow delete this action bar by modifying the styles xml the Activity and the manifest. So now it's a fullscreen activity, even when I use DarkActionBar as parent in styles:

Here my files:
Styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.swagdev.app.swagpoints">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Map"/>
</application>
```

Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.swagdev.app.swagpoints.MainActivity">


<com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    app:zxing_use_texture_view="true"
    android:id="@+id/scanner"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/location_field"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scanner"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="Scan Sticker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvh"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<nl.psdcompany.duonavigationdrawer.views.DuoDrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:tag="content"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:tag="menu"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    </FrameLayout>
</nl.psdcompany.duonavigationdrawer.views.DuoDrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

SO now my toolbar is gone. How do i need to modify styles or activity or manifest to get it back?